# Selecting dynamic input box in Salesforce - Selenium/ Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, salesforce

How can I select the following input box (id=2258:0) with Selenium for python? The id dynamically changes as well as other elements.

```html
<label class="label inputLabel uiLabel-left form-element__label uiLabel" for="2258:0" data-aura-rendered-by="3789:0" data-aura-class="uiLabel"><span class="" data-aura-rendered-by="3790:0">Close Date</span><div class="tooltip-trigger uiTooltip" aria-describedby="tt-for-2283:0" tabindex="0" data-aura-rendered-by="2286:0" data-aura-class="uiTooltip" data-proxy-id="aura-pos-lib-4" id="2286:0"><lightning-icon class="tooltipIcon slds-button__icon slds-icon-utility-info slds-icon_container forceIcon" data-data-rendering-service-uid="963" data-aura-rendered-by="2282:0" data-aura-class="forceIcon"><lightning-primitive-icon lightning-primitiveicon_primitiveicon-host=""><svg lightning-primitiveIcon_primitiveIcon="" focusable="false" data-key="info" aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon_xx-small"><use lightning-primitiveIcon_primitiveIcon="" xlink:href="/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg?cache=9.26.0#info"></use></svg></lightning-primitive-icon></lightning-icon><span class="tooltip-invisible" role="tooltip" id="tt-for-2283:0" data-aura-rendered-by="2288:0">Date the Opportunity Product isClosed</span></div><!--render facet: 3793:0--></label>
    <div class="tooltip-trigger uiTooltip" aria-describedby="tt-for-2283:0" tabindex="0" data-aura-rendered-by="2286:0" data-aura-class="uiTooltip" data-proxy-id="aura-pos-lib-4" id="2286:0"><lightning-icon class="tooltipIcon slds-button__icon slds-icon-utility-info slds-icon_container forceIcon" data-data-rendering-service-uid="963" data-aura-rendered-by="2282:0" data-aura-class="forceIcon"><lightning-primitive-icon lightning-primitiveicon_primitiveicon-host=""><svg lightning-primitiveIcon_primitiveIcon="" focusable="false" data-key="info" aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon_xx-small"><use lightning-primitiveIcon_primitiveIcon="" xlink:href="/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg?cache=9.26.0#info"></use></svg></lightning-primitive-icon></lightning-icon><span class="tooltip-invisible" role="tooltip" id="tt-for-2283:0" data-aura-rendered-by="2288:0">Date the Opportunity Product isClosed</span></div>
        <lightning-icon class="tooltipIcon slds-button__icon slds-icon-utility-info slds-icon_container forceIcon" data-data-rendering-service-uid="963" data-aura-rendered-by="2282:0" data-aura-class="forceIcon"><lightning-primitive-icon lightning-primitiveicon_primitiveicon-host=""><svg lightning-primitiveIcon_primitiveIcon="" focusable="false" data-key="info" aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon_xx-small"><use lightning-primitiveIcon_primitiveIcon="" xlink:href="/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg?cache=9.26.0#info"></use></svg></lightning-primitive-icon></lightning-icon>
        <span class="tooltip-invisible" role="tooltip" id="tt-for-2283:0" data-aura-rendered-by="2288:0">Date the Opportunity Product isClosed</span>
        <div class="tooltip-trigger uiTooltip" aria-describedby="tt-for-2283:0" tabindex="0" data-aura-rendered-by="2286:0" data-aura-class="uiTooltip" data-proxy-id="aura-pos-lib-4" id="2286:0"><lightning-icon class="tooltipIcon slds-button__icon slds-icon-utility-info slds-icon_container forceIcon" data-data-rendering-service-uid="963" data-aura-rendered-by="2282:0" data-aura-class="forceIcon"><lightning-primitive-icon lightning-primitiveicon_primitiveicon-host=""><svg lightning-primitiveIcon_primitiveIcon="" focusable="false" data-key="info" aria-hidden="true" class="slds-icon slds-icon_xx-small"><use lightning-primitiveIcon_primitiveIcon="" xlink:href="/_slds/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg?cache=9.26.0#info"></use></svg></lightning-primitive-icon></lightning-icon><span class="tooltip-invisible" role="tooltip" id="tt-for-2283:0" data-aura-rendered-by="2288:0">Date the Opportunity Product isClosed</span></div>

<div class="form-element" data-aura-rendered-by="2262:0"><input class=" input" type="text" aria-describedby="" id="2258:0" data-aura-rendered-by="2263:0" data-interactive-lib-uid="16" data-proxy-id="aura-pos-lib-13"><a class="datePicker-openIcon display" aria-haspopup="true" data-aura-rendered-by="2265:0" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="assistiveText" data-aura-rendered-by="2266:0">Date Picker</span></a><!--render facet: 2268:0--><!--render facet: 2269:0--></div>
    <input class=" input" type="text" aria-describedby="" id="2258:0" data-aura-rendered-by="2263:0" data-interactive-lib-uid="16" data-proxy-id="aura-pos-lib-13">
    <a class="datePicker-openIcon display" aria-haspopup="true" data-aura-rendered-by="2265:0" href="javascript:void(0);"><span class="assistiveText" data-aura-rendered-by="2266:0">Date Picker</span></a>
```

I've tried the following code with no success:

```py
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Close Date')]/following-sibling::input")
```

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Jeff. had no idea, but makes total sense.

Answer (score 0):

Use XPATH that is in this format

```
//div[@id="container-3"]/fuse-content/div/div[2]/
```

instead of

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Close Date')]/following-sibling::input
```

Comment: //div[@id="container-3"]/fuse-content/div/div[2]/ is just an example

Answer (score 0):

With below CSS locator should work -

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.form-element > input")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if any IFRME exists for that element and then try:

```
//*[contains(text(), 'Close Date')]/following-sibling::input
```